# How to embed existing property editor inside my own custom editor

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, propertyeditor

I'm creating a custom property editor in Umbraco 7. I want to be able to record goals scored in a football game, made up of three pieces of information:

- Minute scored
- Player
- Short description

I'd like the Player attribute to be a Tree Picker which will select a 'Player' doc type from a 'Squad' folder on the Content tree. I'm having difficulty finding documentation on how to do this.

I've already created the editor and added it to a doc type, so I can see it working, but I just want the Player picker to be a content picker.

So my question is; how do you use existing property editors inside your custom editors?

PS: I know that I can use data grids for this, but I'd rather create my own editor.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?